# How to customise the appearance of notify-send?

Tags: notifications, xmonad, notify-send

I am running linux mint and use the `notify-send` command for various purposes, and of course also receive notifications from regular applications e.g. discord or MS Teams

When using Cinnamon DE, they look pretty normal, and I can even add icons to my custom `notify-send` calls to make it clear what is going on

However, I recently started using XMonad WM, and I'm finding that not only are the regular application notifications ugly, but my custom ones which have nice icons in them also follow that same ugly style (please excuse blurry screenshot):

[image]

For example, the above notification should contain an icon as per this command:

```
notify-send --hint=int:transient:1 'Connecting to VPN... Check 2FA Device.' -i myicon
```

Where is this configured?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Systems that do not use a desktop environment usually require installing a separate notification daemon to handle notifications. It appears that you already have the `dunst` notification daemon installed.

To configure its appearance, you can edit `~/.config/dunst/dunstrc`. If it is not available, you can create a copy from `/etc/dunst/dunstrc`.

You can modify many different settings such as `width`, `height`, `font`, `background` and `foreground`, etc.

Once you have modified the config file, you will have to restart `dunst` by killing the process (`pkill dunst`) and starting `dunst` again as a background process (`dunst & disown $!`). Generating a new notification will also usually start the `dunst` daemon but it is recommended to explicitly start `dunst` in case there are multiple notification daemons.

See `man 'dunst(5)'` for details on the configuration file.